# How to give boolean value in @Container in spring data cosmos?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, spring-el

In the below code, I am not able to set autoScale from the configuration property. I am getting errors as "expected boolean but the string is supplied".

```
@Container(containerName = "${dynamic.container.name}"
        , autoScale = "${dynamic.container.autoScale}", ru = "400")
public class FruitsContainer(){
.....
}
```

Kindly let me know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple entities are defined in Cosmos DB as items. And we can do so by adding the **`@Container`** annotation and specifying properties related to the container, like container name, request units (RUs), time to live, auto scale and so on.

- Annotation  `@Container(containerName="myContainer")`  specifies container name in Azure Cosmos DB.
- And by default request units (RUs) assigned to newly created containers is 400. But we can change it to customize it according to our need.
- Lastly, annotation `autoScale` field describes that container to be created with autoscale throughput when set to **`true`**. Check this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/provision-throughput-autoscale) for more information on autoscale.

If you check [Creating Containers with autoscale throughput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/spring-data-cosmos-readme?view=azure-java-stable#creating-containers-with-autoscale-throughput), you will find that you can achieve what you want using the following snippet-

```java
@Container(containerName = "${dynamic.container.name}"
        , autoScale = true, ru = "400")
public class FruitsContainer(){
.....
}
```

Comment: Yes... Thank you, But how can change autoscale value based on environmental configuration?

Comment: `autoScale` field in the @Container only takes **Boolean Values**. By default it is **false**, which means containers are created with **manual throughput**.

Comment: yes, I want to control that per environment. ie in one environment I need to have autoscale enabled and in another, it should be manual.